# What is 'get_source_filename()' used for in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am getting the following error:

```
'MyProfile' object has no attribute 'get_source_filename'
```

The following code is from a previously answered SO question, so I'm not sure what get_source_filename() is or does.  A google search turned up nothing.

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    coverpic = models.ImageField(upload_to="site_media/media/covers/", null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Did we have to resize the image?
        # We pop it to remove from kwargs when we pass these along
            image_resized = kwargs.pop('image_resized',False)
            super(MyProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            if self.coverpic:
                print "yes"
                basewidth = 300
                filename = self.get_source_filename()
                image = Image.open(filename)
                wpercent = (basewidth/float(image.size[0]))
                hsize = int((float(image.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
                img = image.resize((basewidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
                self.coverpic = img
                self.coverpic.save
```

Comment: Its probably a custom method of that model class.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback please.